# investigate the convergence of given series with logarithm

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

investigate the convergence of $$\sum_{n\ge 2}\ln\frac{n^2}{n^2-1}$$

---

I solved this problem:

the series converges because 
$$\int_1^{\infty}\ln\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}dx=2\ln 2<\infty$$
but the integral needs lines of computations, I would like to ask if somebody sees easier/faster convergence proof.

Comment: $f(n)=\ln\left(\dfrac{n^2}{n^2-1}\right)=2\ln(n)-\ln(n-1)-\ln(n+1)$

Comment: After that it is just a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: yeah, it works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log\dfrac{r^2}{r^2-1}=\log\dfrac{r^2}{(r-1)(r+1)}$$

Using $\log a+\log b=\log(ab)$ where each of the logarithm is defined,

$$\sum_{r=2}^n\log\dfrac{r^2}{(r-1)(r+1)}=\log\dfrac{2\cdot(n+1)}{1\cdot n}$$

Answer (score 3):

Another way is using the Weierstrass product of the sine $$\frac{\sin\left(\pi z\right)}{\pi z}=\prod_{n\geq1}\left(1-\frac{z^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)\Rightarrow\frac{\sin\left(\pi z\right)}{\pi z\left(1-z^{2}\right)}=\prod_{n\geq2}\left(1-\frac{z^{2}}{n^{2}}\right)
 $$ and $$\prod_{n\geq2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)=\lim_{z\rightarrow1}\frac{\sin\left(\pi z\right)}{\pi z\left(1-z^{2}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}
 $$ so we can see that $$\sum_{n\geq2}\log\left(\frac{n^{2}}{n^{2}-1}\right)=\log\left(\prod_{n\geq2}\left(1-\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)^{-1}\right)=\color{red}{\log\left(2\right)}.$$