# Evaluating the sum $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln[1-1/n^2]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For convenience the sum is again
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln[1-1/n^2]=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln\frac{(n^2-1)}{(n^2)}
$$
I first tried solving using a definite integral, since this seems to make telescoping easier to see,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln\frac{(n^2-1)}{(n^2)}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln(n^2-1)-\ln(n^2)=
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\int_{n^2}^{n^2-1}\frac{dx}{x}
$$
But writing out the first few terms doesn't make any cancellation obvious because of the $n^2$ terms.

I also tried futzing around with log rules and got things down to 
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln\frac{(n^2-1)}{(n^2)}=
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln((n-1)(n+1))-\ln(n^2)=
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\ln(n-1)+\ln(n+1)-\ln(n^2)
$$
The first few terms of which are
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{4}\ln\frac{(n^2-1)}{(n^2)}=[\ln1+\ln3-2\ln 2]+[\ln2+\ln4-2\ln 3]+[\ln3+\ln5-2\ln 4]+...\\
=\ln 2+\ln 5-2\ln 4
$$
Which leads to the guess that 
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{4}\ln\frac{(n^2-1)}{(n^2)}=\ln (N-1)+\ln(N+2)-2\ln(N)\\
=\ln(\frac{(N-1)(N+2)}{N^2})\rightarrow 0
$$
Which means I'm wrong. Should I soldiering on looking for a pattern through more computation, or is there a more expedient/elegant way to evaluate the sum?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875837/investigate-the-convergence-of-given-series-with-logarithm/1875854#1875854

Comment: Your second-to-last step of combining the log terms together looks very wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were on the right track in writing $$\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\log(n+1)-\log(n)+\log(n-1)-\log(n)$$

Proceeding, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^N \log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)&=\sum_{n=2}^N \left(\log(n+1)-\log(n)\right)+\sum_{n=2}^N \left(\log(n-1)-\log(n)\right)\\\\
&=\log(N+1)-\log(2)-\log(N)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \log\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=-\log(2)$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\prod_{n=2}^N\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)=\prod_{n=2}^N\frac{n^2-1}{n^2}=\prod_{n=2}^N\frac{n+1}{n}\cdot \prod_{n=2}^N\frac{n-1}{n}
$$ then factors telescope.

Take $\ln$ of it and make $N \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\,\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\ln\pars{1 - {1 \over n^{2}}}} & =
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\ln\pars{1 - {1 \over n}} + \ln\pars{1 + {1 \over n}}}
=
\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}\,\,\int_{0}^{1}\pars{%
-\,{1 \over n - t} + {1 \over n + t}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{%
{1 \over n + 2 + t} - {1 \over n + 2- t}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\Psi\pars{2 - t} - \Psi\pars{2 + t}}\,\dd t
\qquad\qquad\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}
\\[5mm] & =
\left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}%
-\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{2 - t}\Gamma\pars{2 + t}}\,\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ 1}
\qquad\qquad\pars{~\Gamma:\ Gamma\ Function~}
\\[5mm] & =
-\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{1}\Gamma\pars{3}} + \ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{2}\Gamma\pars{2}}
=
-\ln\pars{0! \times 2!} + \ln\pars{1! \times 1!}
\\[5mm] & =
\color{#f00}{-\ln\pars{2}}
\end{align}